# Polynomials that satisfy $(x-1)(p(x+1))=(x+2)(p(x))$ where $p(2)=12$?

Tags: polynomials, functional-equations

I am taking a graduate class on Equation Theory and one of my homework questions asks me to "Determine all polynomials $p(x)$ such that $(x-1)(p(x+1))=(x+2)(p(x))$ and $p(2)=12$. A provided hint is to try carefully selected values of $x$.

I've been able to use Excel to "plug and chug" to find values for $x\in\mathbb{Z}\geq1$. ($p(x)=0$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}<1$.) I used Excel to graph the values I found and I was given a trend line that approximated $p(x)=2x^3-2x$.

What might some approaches be to be able to find all such polynomials?
Thanks!

Comment: Find some roots by plugging in values of $x$ to make one of the sides vanish. Factor out the roots: $p(x) = (x-1)(x+1) h(x)$ and plug this into the formula to derive an equation for $h(x)$. Repeat until you get something 'nice'.

Comment: When you consider "infinite" polynomials, you will also find solutions like $p(x) = 2(x^3-x) \cos(2k\pi x)$...

Answer (score 4):

You found a solution $p(x) = 2x^3 - 2x$.

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}, n \geq 2$ holds

$p(n+1) = \frac{n+2}{n-1}p(n)$ with $p(2) = 12$

hence by induction $p$ is determined for all $n\geq 2$.
This means that the solution is unique, and is $2x^3 - 2x$.

Comment: The “$p(x) = 2x^3 - 2x$” solution is found by sketching/approximating/guessing. What you have done is using induction to verify the correctness of the guess. Wondering is it possible to generate that solution, from the raw information, independently and mathematically?

Comment: The attempt of my answer was showing that if the solution exists, then it is unique.

Comment: That is good. The interesting part is can that solution be generated?

Answer (score 2):

We are given that

$$ \frac{ p(x+1) } { p(x) } = \frac{ x+2}{x-1}$$

Let $ p(x) = A \prod ( x - \alpha_i)$.

**Hint:**  If $ \alpha_i \neq 1$, show that for some $j$, $\alpha_j = \alpha_i - 1$.

**Hint:** If $ \alpha_i \neq -1$, show that for some $k$, $ \alpha_k = \alpha_i + 1$.

**Hint:** Use the fact that any polynomial has finite degree.

Conclude that $ p(x) = A [(x-1) x (x+1)] q(x)$, where $ \frac{q(x+1)}{q(x)} = 1 $ for some polynomial $q(x)$.

Show that $q(x)$ is a constant.

Hence, $p(x) = A(x-1)x(x+1)$, and since $p(2) = 12$, we can find $A=2$.

---

In particular, this helps you characterize all possible equations of the form

$$ f(x) p(x) = g(x) p(x+1)$$

which have a non-trivial solution.

Comment: There is no reason to assume that $A$ is a constant - it can be a polynomial as well...

Comment: @johannesvalks All the "polynomial part" have been pulled out. In particular, A is simply the leading coefficient of $p(x)$.

Comment: Yes you are correct - the $q(x)$ is a polynomial... Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: It is always difficult to do math. and watch the worldcup...

Answer (score 1):

Think about roots of this polynomial. Notice that, $x=-1,0$ are roots of this polynomial. 
What can you tell about the polynomial, if you know one of its roots? That it must be divisible by $(x-a)$ where $a$ is root of this polynomial. Try to use this in this problem, i am sure you will  be able to complete it.  :)

Comment: Why must $x=-1, 0$ be a root of this polynomial? Can you add an explanation? How do you know that it doesn't have any other roots?

Comment: @CalvinLin From the stated identity, if we use $x=1$, we get $0=2p(0)$, which means $p(0)=0$. If we use $x=2$, we get $-3p(-1)=0$. Therefore $-1$ and $0$ *are* roots of $p$.

Comment: @egreg Yes I know that. I meant for him to add more of an explanation. Note that the question about "any other roots" still remains valid. All that he can conclude is that $(x-1)(x+1)x$ divides $p(x)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin It appears that any integer $\leq 1$ is a root.

Comment: @BSquire Not necessarily so. See my solution.

Comment: @CalvinLin, Notice that it is a homework problem, i just gave a hint to start the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Given the condition

$$
(x-1) p(x+1) = (x+2) p(x) \wedge p(2) = 12.
$$

We find

$$
p(x-1) = \frac{x-2}{x+1} p(x) \wedge p(2) = 12 \Rightarrow p(1)=0, p(0)=0, p(-1)=0,
$$

i.e. we have the zeros $-1, 0, +1$. So we can write

$$
p(x) = (x-1)x(x+1) f(x),
$$

where

$$
f(2) = 2.
$$

Whence

$$
(x-1)x(x+1)(x+2) f(x+1) = (x-1)x(x+1)(x+2) f(x),
$$

so

$$
f(x) = f(x+1).
$$

So the function $f(x)$ is periodic.

When we consider "infinite" polynomials, we can think of $f(x) = 2\cos(2 k \pi x)$.
So we obtain for example

$$
p(x) = 2(x-1)x(x+1) \cos(2 k \pi x),
$$

as a solution.

The case $k=0$ yields

$$
p(x) = 2(x-1)x(x+1) = 2x^3-2x,
$$

but this is not the only solution!

Comment: Polynomials are not "infinite". But even then, there are more solutions than what you listed.

Comment: @CalvinLin: Well, I clearly wrote "When we consider" and "for example"...

Comment: @johannesvalks I'm curious as to how you determined that $f(2)=2$. I'm also wondering how to handle all the roots $\leq 1$. I'm thinking about saying something like $p(x)=(x-1)(x)(x+1)(x+2)...(x+n)...f(x)$.

Comment: @BSquire, as $p(2)=12$ and $p(x) = (x-1)x(x+1) f(x)$, we obtain $12=6 f(2)$, thus $f(2)=2$...

Comment: @BSquire: Given the condition we only find the roots for $-1$, $0$, and $+1$, and we find a polynomial $f(x)$ that satisfies $f(x) = f(x+1)$.